# integrating soapUI report into sonar

Tags: maven, junit, continuous-integration, soapui, sonarqube

I have the following setup. I use maven /soapUI maven plugin /soapUI to execute tests on a webservice. My target is to display the test results in sonar. As there is no real build going on in maven, there is nothing to analyze for sonar (if i understood that correct).  Is there a a soapUI report format, that can be reused by sonar? Has anyone made experiences with such a setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try and run soapui from Junit?

http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html

Maven will run them automatically as part of the build and Sonar should display the results normally.